# How to run bin/console messenger:consume command out of Symfony project?

Tags: php, consumer, symfony-console, symfony-messenger

I use [Messenger Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) in a non-Symfony project and Doctrine as a DSN transport. Now I want to test my code and consume the messages on my local machine, but I don't know how to run the messenger command in the console.

I tried to use `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` and register the `\Symfony\Component\Messenger\Command\ConsumeMessagesCommand` command in the console but there are many nested dependencies.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We actually do this in many projects, even WordPress CLI tools, and we use this [library](https://github.com/queue-interop/queue-interop) to do it along with [this](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/transport/dbal.md) for the transport. It doesn't require Symfony and can work with most queue systems that follow the general standard.

The general idea is that you want something (probably a singleton) to return an instance of `Interop\Queue\Context`, and here's what we use:

```php
    function createContext(): \Interop\Queue\Context
    {
        $factory = new \Enqueue\Dbal\DbalConnectionFactory(
            sprintf(
                'mysql://%1$s:%2$s@%3$s/%4$s',
                DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD,
                DB_HOST,
                DB_NAME
            )
        );

        $context = $factory->createContext();
        $context->createDataBaseTable();
        return $context;
    }
```

You'll also want something to handle each message, and you'll want to pass the message and consumer to it:

```php
    function handleMessage($message, $consumer)
    {
        // Business logic here
        if($business_logic_failed) {
            $context = createContext();
            $failed_queue = $context->createQueue('FAILED_QUEUE_HERE');
            $context->createProducer()->send($failed_queue, $message);
        } else {
            $consumer->acknowledge($message);
        }
        
    }
```

Then to use it:

```php
$context = createContext();
$queue = $context->createQueue('QUEUE_NAME_HERE');
$consumer = $context->createConsumer($queue);

// This can be an infinite loop, or a loop for 10 messages and exit, whatever your logic
while(true) {
    // This command will block unless you pass a timeout, so no sleep is needed
    $message = $consumer->receive(/* optional timeout here */);
    handleMessage($message, $consumer);

    // Do whatever you want with message
}
```

Sprinkle a lot of try/catch around that, too, and make sure that no matter what you acknowledge or fail the message in some way.